# Print invoice in Sales>Orders Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

```
Error: Call to a member function getStoreId() on null in /Users/mac14/Sites/cleanlinesurf-upgrade/app/code/Fooman/PdfCustomiser/Block/AbstractSalesDocument.php:180
```

I'm getting this error on print Invoice from Action dropdown in Sales>Orders on admin side. Here is the code:

```
$storeId = $this->getSalesObject()->getStoreId();
if ($storeId === null) {
   $store = $this->_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView();
   $storeId = $store->getId();
}
return $storeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting

```
Fooman_PdfCustomiser_Helper_Pdf $helper
```

Then use

```
$helper->getStoreId()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
protected $_storeManager;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }
```